# Replace value in one column with value from another column in the same row with certain condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with columns "A", "B", and "Dict"

- "Dict" has values of either "A" or "B" , which indicates the correct
  columns that values should be in for each row
- columns "A" or "B" have numeric values

For example:

```
A            B             Dict
0           123            B
0           123            A
123         0              A
```

I want to move the value in "B" to "A" if "Dict" has A in the same row, but keep other rows the same if the "Dict" has correct matchings (the value should be in the column that "Dict" indicates,  otherwise it will be 0):

```
A            B             Dict
0           123             B
123          0              A
123          0              A
```

Does anyone know how I should proceed?

Edit: There are negative values in the columns too. Sorry I should've clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to Darren Tsai. Using his solution we could use `A+B` instead of `pmax` because of the 0:

With this dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(0L, 0L, 123L), B = c(123L, 123L, 0L), Dict = c("B", 
"A", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(A:B, ~ ifelse(Dict == cur_column(), A+B, 0)))
```

I get this:

```
    A   B Dict
1   0 123    B
2 123   0    A
3 123   0    A
```

Comment: I think this does not work in case where Dict=="A" and B should be assigned to 0

Comment: I have changed the answer!

Comment: For some reason it is turning both of my columns A and B into all 0's, some values in the columns are negative, would it be because of that?

Comment: I have updated and added the used df. It should work! The important thing is that the 0 must be the counterpart of the number to be changed so A == 123 B == 0 will work, but A == 123 and B== 1 won't work. to overcome the negative number we could use `abs(A+B)` instead of `A+B`

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`, you could use `Dict == cur_column()` in `across()` to determine where to swap A and B.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(A:B, ~ ifelse(Dict == cur_column(), pmax(A, B), pmin(A, B))))

    A   B Dict
1   0 123    B
2 123   0    A
3 123   0    A
```

Comment: The only issue is there are also negative values in the column, sorry I should've clarified.

Answer (score 3):

Another base R:

```r
ind <- dat$Dict != c("A","B")[max.col(dat[,c("A","B")])]
ind
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
dat[ind,c("A","B")] <- dat[ind,c("B","A")]
dat
#     A   B Dict
# 1   0 123    B
# 2 123   0    A
# 3 123   0    A
```

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(A = c(0L, 123L, 123L), B = c(123L, 0L, 0L), Dict = c("B", "A", "A")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work :

```
df$A=ifelse(df$Dict=="A" & df$A==0,df$B,ifelse(df$Dict=="A",df$A,0))
df$B=ifelse(df$Dict=="B" & df$B==0,df$A,ifelse(df$Dict=="B",df$B,0))

df
    A   B Dict
1   0 123    B
2 123   0    A
3 123   0    A
```